# What happens when there's no upper limit for a sum

Tags: summation, notation

I have seen this a few times and am kind of confused, can someone please explain?

Edit: Sorry, perhaps I wasn't specific enough. How Do you determine what the upper limit is equal to if it isn't shown? (Would it be infinite)

Example:

[image: enter link description here]

Comment: Please provide a reference which shows the notation you are thinking of.

Comment: Like in the Shapley value equation

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: That link does not appear to work.  In any case, edit your post to include the reference(s).  Don't leave it in the comments.

Comment: That sum is over all sets $S$ which are subsets of some previously specified set.

Comment: Thank you! I learn summation notation recently, trying to get ahead but I had some question's I'm not really that good at self teaching.